# Expo app crashing on Android and iOS platforms but works in web

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, cross-platform

I am quite new to expo app development, I first built it for web and I was trying to convert it for mobile apps too. Here's the Snack App link, can anyone help me point in the right direction? I have spent hours on this [Snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@mensour/ffceca)

I tried running it on Snack and on localhost. It worked fine in web for both cases but apps did not.